# Counting uppercase and lowercase. A better way to specify the alphabets?

Tags: cobol

Given this working version

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. HELLO-WORLD.
DATA DIVISION.
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
    01 UC-COUNTER PIC 99.
    01 LC-COUNTER PIC 99.
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
    INSPECT "My dog has fleas"
     TALLYING UC-COUNTER FOR ALL 'A','B','C','D','E','F',
        'G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T',
        'U','V','W','X','Y','Z' 
        LC-COUNTER FOR ALL 'a','b','c','d','e','f',
        'g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t',
        'u','v','w','x','y','z'.
    DISPLAY UC-COUNTER " UPPER CASE CHARACTERS".
    DISPLAY LC-COUNTER " LOWER CASE CHARACTERS".
    
    GOBACK.
```

Is there a better way of expressing the alphabets? That is, can we have a SPECIAL-NAMES or something like that so that the instruction can be INSPECT TALLYING FOR ALL LATIN-UPPERCASE-LETTERS-ENGLISH or something similar.

**LATER**

Things like this don't appear to work (and given the GnuCOBOL docs, probably won't)

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. HELLO-WORLD.
ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
CONFIGURATION SECTION.
SPECIAL-NAMES.
  CLASS UPPER-CASE-ENGLISH-LETTERS IS
   'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M',
   'N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'.
DATA DIVISION.
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
    01 UC-COUNTER PIC 99.
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
    INSPECT "My dog has fleas"
     TALLYING UC-COUNTER FOR ALL UPPER-CASE-ENGLISH-LETTERS.
    DISPLAY UC-COUNTER " UPPER CASE CHARACTERS".
    STOP RUN.
```

Comment: Note: you likely want to have a look at the COBOL standard document, you may find the DIS at https://isotc.iso.org/livelink/livelink?func=ll&objId=21916208 and drafts in general at https://isotc.iso.org/livelink/livelink?func=ll&objId=19468956

Answer (score 3):

*Is there a better way of expressing the alphabets?*

COBOL has the class conditions `ALPHABETIC-UPPER` and `ALPHABETIC-LOWER`. Each of these includes space as part of the class condition. Unfortunately, for what you are requesting, class conditions cannot be used in an `INSPECT` statement.

It is necessary to *simulate* the `INSPECT` statement by using a loop to *inspect* each character to determine if it meets the class conditions while excluding spaces.

Code:

```
   data division.
   working-storage section.
   01 uc-counter pic 99.
   01 lc-counter pic 99.
   01 str pic x(50).
   01 n comp pic 9(4).
   procedure division.
       initialize uc-counter lc-counter
       string "My dog has fleas" low-value delimited size
           into str
       perform varying n from 1 by 1
       until str(n:1) = low-value
           evaluate true
           when str(n:1) = space
               continue             *> ignore space
           when str(n:1) is alphabetic-upper
               add 1 to uc-counter  *> count upper-case letter
           when str(n:1) is alphabetic-lower
               add 1 to lc-counter  *> count lower-case letter
           when other
               continue
           end-evaluate
       end-perform
       display uc-counter " upper case characters"
       display lc-counter " lower case characters"
       goback
       .
```

Output:

```
01 upper case characters
12 lower case characters
```

Comment: stringing in the low-value I've not seen before but it makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: @SimonSobisch - `INSPECT` General rules requires *sequential* comparisons for each character. Hence `"A" "B" ... "Y" "Z"` would require 1 compare for "A" and 26 compares for "Z". Further, `"a" "b" ... "y" "z"`, appearing after the upper-case letters would require 52 compares for "z" and for any other characters not listed. GR 7 in 2002 or GR8 in later versions.

Comment: I agree. to the inspect rules leading to 52 _internal_ comparisons to match "z" while iterating over each character manually allows the internal check to be optimized (for example with a table lookup using the value as index).
But the manual loop needs 1 addition (get value, change value, store value) for all integers for each position (+position n), so I _think_ that is quite likely to take longer. Can you verify with some compilers [I'll check with GnuCOBOL]?

Comment: I've said that `INSPECT` is faster before, but I stand corrected.

Using a GnuCOBOL debug runtime: INSPECT takes 0.4% more executed instructions (when using `N USAGE BINARY-INT``), and still better with all runtime checks enabled.

Comment: @SimonSobisch - I ran four tests on my old Micro Focus 16-bit compiler (love the IDE). Horrid performance with user-defined `class` in `special-names`. Slow with posted code likely due to library call. About 8 times faster than posted code with `inspect`. Twice faster than `inspect` with `evaluate str(n:1)` and range checks, `when "A" thru "Z"` etc.

Comment: @SimonSobisch - Further, to my previous comment, for the sample data, the average number of comparisons per character with `inspect` changes dramatically with the order of characters: upper then lower: 37.68, lower then upper: 19.81, space then lower then upper: 11.06. That is, the `inspect` runs faster if spaces are counted.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what character set you are using, if the characters are contiguous, then you could suffice with a few comparisons.

Comment: How would you do that? The inspect _internally_ checks all positions against all literals and counts as needed